# Orders coming through without shipping method selected/no shipping charge

Tags: shipping

Running Magento 1.8. Twice in the last year orders have come through without any shipping charges. We use a mixture of table rates and calculated rates.

Anyone else ever see this? Any ideas? We just were informed of the orders and it's been over a month since the last one.

Comment: Can you replicate this issue using the exact order info?

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. We don't have anything to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this issue on a few sites running OneStepCheckout.com. There seems to be a problem around the way it processes the ajax callbacks. If you are running this speak to them, or another checkout extension.

I've never seen this issue on any magento sites that do not have a custom checkout.

Comment: Yep, they were running OneStepCheckout. I never figured out what was allowing them through, but I did move them to another OSC.